# Is $S^1$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^1$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am supposed to construct a homeomorphism of $S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}P^1$ but I am not toally sure that this is even possible. I think I have learned at some point that
$$\mathbb{R}P^1=S^1/\{x=-x\}$$

Thank you.

Comment: You should definitely check if you have learned that or not!

Comment: You might want to lok at my answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064912/looking-for-a-homeomorphism-mathbbcp1-cong-s2/1064947#1064947 where you can modify easely the argument from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

As $z\mapsto z^2$ (or $e^{it}\mapsto e^{2it}$) shows, we have $S^1\approx S^1/\{x=-x\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on $S^1$ identifying antipodal points.  Clearly $S^1/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^1$, what isn't clear is that $S^1$ is homeomorphic to $S^1/\sim$.  But notice the latter space is homeomorphic to a semicircle with endpoints identified, which is clearly homeomorphic to $S^1$, hence $S^1\simeq S^1/\sim\simeq\mathbb{R}P^1$.

Edit: Thanks for fix Kevin, I didn't notice my typos.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* possible, as the two spaces are indeed homeomorphic.